How to download images from urls that do not contain file extensions using jszip
I am trying to download images into a zip folder using jszip.
The issue:
The image url that has a file extension at the end is downloaded fine. When the url doesn't have a file extension, the downloaded file doesn't a file extension. Example:
This here is a valid image https://arweave.net/ba-pnARBlB5TW4vyC0lKUS28hZwbbNB0DVMWtZmD4sM
When I download this image the file name is ba-pnARBlB5TW4vyC0lKUS28hZwbbNB0DVMWtZmD4sM  without the file extension, unlike this one image https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg which downloads fine as MainAfter.jpg
I need to properly download the images that do not end with file extensions too.
Here is a link to a similar project in codepen. I am unable to paste the jszip.min.js file here please take a look here https://codepen.io/xyla/pen/rQKQEd
What I have:

  <p>
    This demo requires a recent browser, see <a href="https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html">
  the howto</a>.
  </p>
  <div id="downloader_application">
    <h3>Please select your files</h3>
    <form action="#" id="download_form">
      <ul>

         <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="fl" data-folder="css" data-url="https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg" checked /> IMG1
          </label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
             Sample
           </div>
        </li>
           <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="fl" data-folder="css" data-url="https://arweave.net/ba-pnARBlB5TW4vyC0lKUS28hZwbbNB0DVMWtZmD4sM" checked /> IMG2
          </label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
             Sample
           </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
    </form>

    <p class="hide" id="result"></p>

  </div>



Whatever mechanism you have that downloads these images should check the mime type, and choose an extension based on that.  For example, your arweave.net image has the following response header:  Content-Type: image/png
